# Php function modifications and check

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify function in php in order to get desired result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137456/modify-function-in-php-in-order-to-get-desired-result)

i'm doing this module, and with the help of some people her ei've been progressing.

I'm trying to get facebook user likes but i can't apparently... it brings me out nothing..

Can you please check if there's any error in this function..?

Thanks

```
function _facebook_graph_friends_list() {

    global $user;
    if(!empty($user->uid)){

        $fbuid = facebook_graph_get_fbuid();
        $return = '';

        if(!empty($fbuid)){
            $facebook = facebook_client();
            $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

            if(!empty($friends['data'])){
                $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
                $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';

                foreach($friends['data'] as $data){
                    $fbid = $data['id'];
                    $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 

                    foreach($fbfriendslikes['data'] as $data){
                        $fbname = $data['name'];
                        $fbid1 = $data['id'];
                        $path = $protocol . '://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid1 . '/picture?type=' . $size;
                        $image = theme('image', array('path' => $path, 'alt' => $fbname));
                        $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
                        $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid1.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';
                        $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
```

Comment: Just a question, does $friends get index ['data'] automagically from $facebook->api(); ?

Comment: Holy nested if-loop structure, Batman! O_O

Comment: yes, it does Bono... but i'm stressing out with this thing.. i never had anything to do with facebook :(

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a problem with facebook, not with your code. 
What you need is probably the friends_likes permission. Also, your friends may have disabled viewing their likes (this is a privacy setting).